# Android - EditText won't let the keyboard disappear

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` and I need it to lose focus *and* make the keyboard disappear when the user presses 'Done' on the keyboard. My code goes like:

```
etFromCustom.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlay_dummy)).requestFocus(); //this is what I have to do - send focus to a dummy layout
            return true;
        }               
        return false;
    }
});
```

I know that, by default, the 'Done' key on the keyboard hides the software keyboard, but since I overrode it it doesn't work anymore: the `EditText` does lose focus, but the keyboard, instead of disappearing, just turns from numeric one to qwerty one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add this code in your xml. particular `EditText` in you xml file.

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
    getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS); use this code to disappear keyboard

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

put in create activity

```
private InputMethodManager imm;
imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);



DoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
            //  yourEditTextView.setText("");

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        searchEditTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```